# Selenium radiobutton selection

Tags: selenium

I have an HTML code as follows:

```
<label class="top" for="id_gender2">
<div id="uniform-id_gender2" class="radio">
<span>
<input id="id_gender2" type="radio" value="2" name="id_gender">
</span>
</div>
Mrs.
</label>
```

The radio button is getting selected after mouse hover.

I have tried with all possible attributes for selection but I am getting element not found exception.Please let me know how to write java script in webdriver.

Comment: Show code that returns element not found exception

Comment: WebElement selectGender=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='id_gender2']"));
  selectGender.click();

Comment: Also,I can select the radio button after mouse hover. when I keep mouse over the radio button, class="radio hover"

Comment: Can you provide two `HTML` codes: for radio-button before mouse hovering and after?

Comment: <div class="radio-inline">
<label class="top" for="id_gender1">
<div id="uniform-id_gender1" class="radio hover">
<span class="">
<input id="id_gender1" type="radio" value="1" name="id_gender">
</span>
</div>
Mr. 
</label>


On selection:
<div class="radio-inline">
<label class="top" for="id_gender1">
<div id="uniform-id_gender1" class="radio">
<span class="">
<input id="id_gender1" type="radio" value="1" name="id_gender">
</span>
</div>
Mr. 
</label>

Comment: <div class="radio-inline">
<label class="top" for="id_gender1">
<div id="uniform-id_gender1" class="radio hover">
<span class="">
<input id="id_gender1" type="radio" value="1" name="id_gender">
</span>
</div>
Mr. 
</label>


On selection:
<div class="radio-inline">
<label class="top" for="id_gender1">
<div id="uniform-id_gender1" class="radio">
<span class="">
<input id="id_gender1" type="radio" value="1" name="id_gender">
</span>
</div>
Mr. 
</label>

Comment: They seem to be totally the same. Does radio button becomes checked after mouse hover or it becomes available for selection (so you can click on it)? I mean, do you need just to hover to select required option or to click on this option?

Comment: I have to click on option for selection

Comment: site :  http://automationpractice.com

Comment: on this site:
clicon sign in-->create an account-->selection of radiobutton in account creation page

Answer (score 1):

Try following code and let me know the result:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement hover = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='radio hover']"));
action.moveToElement(hover).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id_gender2']"))).click().build().perform();
```

**UPDATE**

Actually there is no need in mouse hover. Target radio seem to be initially non-clickable, so you just need extra time to wait for page complete rendering:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input#id_gender2")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#id_gender2")).click();
```

Comment: still getting the same error "Unable to find element with xpath=="

Comment: which element is not found? You didn't specified element's `XPath`

Comment: By.xpath("//*[@class='radio hover']" not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try javascript executor as follow:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_gende‌​r2"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I think `JavaScript` should be used only as last resort cause it doesn't provide user's behavior imitation

Answer (score 0):

Your element is probably not loaded properly while getting error. You'd better use explicit wait in your script. Wait until your specific element loaded to be visible/clickable. I think, this may help you.

**Code snippet:**

```
    By yourElementToSelect = By.id("id_gender2");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(yourElementToSelect));         
    driver.findElement(yourElementToSelect).click();
```